# JQuery Ajax doesn't work in MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

In User management, there's 4 pages: **List**, **Create**, **Details** and **Edit**. All 4 pages render the partial **ListPartial**.
Here's the Ajax script I use to load the ListPartial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.leftContainer').load('ListPartial');
    });
</script>
```

The **List** and **Create** work correctly but **Details** and **Edit** don't. And I've found the way to make it work by using the url "**User/Details?id=1**" instead of the normal "**User/Details/1**". How can I make it work correctly with the normal url?

**Edited:**

ListPartial.cshtml (Where the link direct to user details page and 4 views **List**, **Create**, **Details** and **Edit** use Ajax to load it)

```
@model IEnumerable<ARS.Models.User>
<div class="leftToolbar">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User"))
{
    <button name="button" class="btnAdd" value="Create"></button>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" class="txtSearch" />
}
</div>
<div class="smallList">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Email đăng nhập
            </th>
            <th>
                Nhóm
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email).ToString(), "Details", new { id=item.ID })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Group.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

UserController/Details

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    return View(user);
}
```

Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: It seems a problem with your routing. Post your routing rules also

Comment: Here it is: routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

Comment: So, I use jQuery AJAX all the time in MVC3, so what are you doing DIFFERENTLY? Also, are you familiar with the Url Helper? You might want to read up on that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: I think I'm not doing differently. I don't understand why it works with "Details?id=1" but "Details/1".

Comment: can you show your action result

Comment: U mean the Details function in Controller? If yes here it is: public ViewResult Details(int id){User user = db.Users.Find(id);return View(user);}. I'm Vietnamese and not good in English. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you update your post with the View code where do you have the Edit and Details links?

Comment: I've updated my post. Take a look.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try User/Details/1 ?

Comment: The Details page didn't load the partial.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller

```
// GET: /User/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
           //code..
        }

// GET: /User/Details/5
public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
           //code..
        }
```

In cshtml page

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserId}) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserId })
```

Comment: Here's Details function:public ViewResult Details(int id){User user = db.Users.Find(id);return View(user);}

Comment: All I do is the same yours. I enter in the web browser "User/Details?id=1" it worked. But didn't with "User/Details/1".